# ng-map. text inside shape?

Tags: angularjs, shapes, ng-map

does anyone know if it is possible to have text inside a shape with ng-map.

```
<ng-map default-style="true" zoom="18" center="53.25564575, -113.81401062" map-type-id="SATELLITE">
  <shape name="rectangle"
    editable="true"
    draggable="true"
    bounds="[[53.2559199723254, -113.81282455825806],[53.25598021665402, -113.81252316761015 ]]"
    on-bounds_changed="vm.boundsChanged()"
    stroke-color="#333"
   stroke-opacity="0.9"
   stroke-weight="2"
   fill-color="#FF0000"
   fill-opacity="0.8"
    >
  </shape>
</ng-map>
```

any ideas how?

Comment: Where is `ng-map` coming from? Could you provide more information and maybe a JSFiddle to demonstrate your problem? With only the template above, nobody wont be able to help you.

Comment: I should have mentioned that ng-map is an angular directive.  https://ngmap.github.io/.

Comment: Can you tell me please how did you get the coordinates when the shape is edited?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved this problem:

first, I added my shapes normally:

```
<shape ng-repeat="zone in mapViewCtrl.displayedZones" name="polygon" fill-color="{{zone.hexColor}}" stroke-color="{{zone.hexColor}}" stroke-opacity="{{zone.fillColor.a/100}}" stroke-weight="2" paths="{{zone.paths}}"></shape>'
```

then calculated the average of points, to get a point around the centre:

```
getAveragePoint(points) {
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    let n = points.length;
    for (let point of points) {
        x += point[0];
        y += point[1];
    }
    return [x / n, y / n];
}
```

then I added a custom marker at the centre point to show my text:

```
<custom-marker ng-repeat="zone in mapViewCtrl.displayedZones" position="{{zone.center}}"><div class="zone-title"><b>{{zone.name}}</b></div></custom-marker>
```

I hope this help